# How to fetch data in ReactJS from NodeJS API for Influxdb?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB as database, I used influxdb-nodejs library module to create API to write data and Query data from Influxdb.

The Queryfunction.js API code is as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  queryfunc: function() {
const Influx = require('influxdb-nodejs');
const client = new Influx('http://127.0.0.1:8086/mydb');
client.query('http')
  .where('type', '2')
   .then(console.info)
   .catch(console.error);
  }
}
```

I use a script.js file to call queryfunc() in Queryfunction.js API:

```js
const myModule = require('./Queryfunction');
let val = myModule.queryfunc();
```

I use command node script to run the script file.
The result is an array
 C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\reactApp\API>node script

{ results: [ { statement_id: 0, series: [Array] } ] }

I am using ReactJS to create front end UI components. How to fetch the resultant array data in ReactJS?

Comment: You have to create rest api first use express.js for create rest api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're either need to write to a json file or you'll need to have an express wrapper around your db calls.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();

 app.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
  const Influx = require('influxdb-nodejs');
  const client = new Influx('http://127.0.0.1:8086/mydb');
   client.query('http')
   .where('type', '2')
   .then(data => res.json(data)
   .catch(err => next(err)); // error middleware to handle
 }

app.listen('3000', () => console.log('running on http://localhost:3000'))
```

Within react you do a fetch:

```
Class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000')
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(data => this.setState( {data} ) )

  render() {
   ....
  }
}
```